# How to format InstallDate property used in Select-Object?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

The InstallDate property used in the below code -

```
$InstalledProgram |  Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, 
InstallDate  | Format-Table –AutoSize

$logDisplayName = $InstalledProgram.DisplayName 
$logPublisher = $InstalledProgram.Publisher
$logVersion = $InstalledProgram.DisplayVersion
$logInstallDate= $InstalledProgram.InstallDate
```

It displays the date of an installed application in this format `20170921` but i want it to be displayed in `21/09/2017` i.e `DD/MM/YYYY` format. How can i format it?

Below is the Entire Code which is used to copy the output to log file:-

```
Clear-Host
$scriptPath = $PSScriptRoot
$logFilePath= Join-path $scriptPath "POCTestResults.log"

# If log file exists, then clear its contents 
if (Test-Path $logFilePath)
{
    clear-content -Path $logFilePath
} 

# It displays the date and time of execution of powershell script in log file.
$log = "Date Of Testing: {0} " -f (Get-Date)
$logString = "Process Started." 
add-content -Path $logFilePath -Value $log -Force 
add-content -Path $logFilePath -Value $logString -Force 
add-content -Path $logFilePath -Value "`n" -Force



# Validate ADD/Remove Program list
# FUNCTION DEFINITIONS
function Log-InstalledProgram($InstalledProgram, $LogFilePath)
{
    #$InstalledProgram |  Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate  | 
    #Format-Table –AutoSize
    $InstalledProgram |  Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, @{Name="InstallDate"; Expression={([datetime]::ParseExact($_.InstallDate, 'yyyyMMdd', $null)).toshortdatestring()}}  | Format-Table –AutoSize

$logDisplayName = $InstalledProgram.DisplayName 
$logPublisher = $InstalledProgram.Publisher
$logVersion = $InstalledProgram.DisplayVersion
$logInstallDate= $InstalledProgram.InstallDate

    add-content -Path $LogFilePath -Value "Product Name: $logDisplayName" -Force   
    add-content -Path $LogFilePath -Value "Publisher: $logPublisher" -Force  
    add-content -Path $LogFilePath -Value "Version: $logVersion" -Force  
    add-content -Path $LogFilePath -Value "InstallDate: $logInstallDate" -Force  
    add-content -Path $LogFilePath -Value "`n" -Force
}

add-content -Path $logFilePath -Value "`n" -Force
add-content -Path $logFilePath -Value "Add/Remove Programs :" -Force
add-content -Path $logFilePath -Value "`n" -Force

$InstalledPrograms = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*

foreach ($InstalledProgram in $InstalledPrograms )
{
    foreach ($displayName in "IntelliMatch Operational Control","intelliSuite Management Studio", "SunGard System Analyzer", "STeP")
    {
        if(($InstalledProgram.DisplayName -ne $Null) -and ($InstalledProgram.DisplayName.Contains($displayName)))
        {
            Log-InstalledProgram $InstalledProgram $logFilePath
        }
    }
}
```

This is script i have used.

Comment: Use a calculated property: `@{Name="InstallDate"; Expression={[DateTime]::ParseExact($_.InstallDate, 'yyyyMMdd', $null)}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[datetime]::ParseExact()` method and [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) to retrieve a datetime format in the `Select-Object` and format it in a short date string with `.toshortdatestring()` :

```
$InstalledProgram |  Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, @{Name="InstallDate"; Expression={([datetime]::ParseExact($_.InstallDate, 'yyyyMMdd', $null)).toshortdatestring()}}  | Format-Table –AutoSize

$logDisplayName = $InstalledProgram.DisplayName 
$logPublisher = $InstalledProgram.Publisher
$logVersion = $InstalledProgram.DisplayVersion
$logInstallDate= $InstalledProgram.InstallDate
```

Comment: This code change works but only in powershell prompt but when i try to copy it to the log file it stills copy it in this format  20170928  yyyymmdd. For eg - Product Name: STeP Apps
Publisher: Manufacturer
Version: 128.0.0
InstallDate: 20170920

Comment: This is how i add it to log :-                                                                                                                                                                                 
add-content -Path $LogFilePath -Value "InstallDate: $logInstallDate" -Force

Comment: Are you sure `$logInstallDate` is not set somewhere else in your code and get the value in the wrong format? I tried to add content in a log and the date format is the right one. `Add-Content -Path "c:\temp\test.txt" -Value (([datetime]::ParseExact('20170928', 'yyyyMMdd', $null)).toshortdatestring())`

Comment: NO, The $logInstallDate is not set somewhere. It gets the value from   $InstalledProgram.InstallDate

Comment: Show the code whith logging part as with these few informations it's not possible to help you

Comment: How can i Add the Code? Sorry i am new so i dont no?

Comment: Edit your question with the logging part

Comment: Try with this : `$InstalledProgram = $InstalledProgram |  Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, @{Name="InstallDate"; Expression={([datetime]::ParseExact($_.InstallDate, 'yyyyMMdd', $null)).toshortdatestring()}}`. You don't save `$InstalledProgram`, you just display it in the console with the select filter so the modifications are not applied. You need to store the modifications in a variable (I use the same)

Comment: Thanks manu :-),It works properly in log file now but in powershell prompt it doesn't display the output but it can be overlooked for now because it was important for me to display in log file and also It gets copied in MM/DD/YYYY format is there is any way by which i can make it DD/MM/YYYY ?

Comment: Something like this : `([datetime]::ParseExact($_.InstallDate,"yyyyMMdd",[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`